# This SQL query won't work

Tags: c#, sql

I Have three tables:

```
Clients: Client_ID, Client_Name, Client_Status,  
Employees:Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Role  
EmpJobs:Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Client_ID, Client_Name, Hours_Spent, Job_Date
```

I'm trying to insert data (Hours_Spent, Job_Date) to EmpJobs based on related columns in Clients and Employees

Should I use Insert or Update Set?

this my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=baker-pc;Initial Catalog=BakodahDB;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("");
    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand.CommandText = (@"UPDATE EmpJobs SET (Hours_Spent, Job_Date) VALUES ('" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "') WHERE Client_Name='"+comboBox1.SelectedItem+"' AND Emp_Name='"+comboBox2.SelectedItem+"'");
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Loged!")
```

Comment: **Your query is vulnerable** - consider using [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html) instead. Your update query is incorrect too - you've followed the insert query format so swapping `update` for `insert` would be alright - although it'll still be vulnerable :)

Comment: And to be sure, with "My SQL query" you mean *Your* (SQL Server compatible) SQL query, and not a MySQL query?

Comment: If the data exists, and you want to change it then use update. If the record does not exist then use insert. Insert is similar to creating a new file and saving it. Update is opening the file, modifying it, and then saving it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi i'm still not sure what should I use, because in EmpJob there's columns that are related to other tables, so they exist. and then there's columns I need to insert new data into (Hours_Spent, Job_Date)

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes it's SQL Server

Comment: @Baker then use update. If the row exists then it's an update. Follow Unlucky's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me point out few mistakes in the code that you have posted.

1. Syntax errors in the Update Query.

I think you forgot the basic syntax of an update query, You can't give values like insert instead of that you have to specify the values for each columns separately. the [basic syntax for Update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) is like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

2. Beware of [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
The second thing that you have to note is that your code opens a wide door for hackers through Injection. You have to use parameterized queries to avoid injection. Then the code will be like the following:

```
string sqlQuery = "UPDATE EmpJobs SET Hours_Spent=@Hours_Spent, Job_Date =@Job_Date" + 
                  " WHERE Client_Name=@Client_Name AND Emp_Name=@Emp_Name"

sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Hours_Spent",SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox3.SelectedItem;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Job_Date",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Client_Name",SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Name",SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = comboBox2.SelectedItem;
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = (@"UPDATE EmpJobs SET Hours_Spent='" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "',Job_Date='" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "') WHERE Client_Name='"+comboBox1.SelectedItem+"' AND Emp_Name='"+comboBox2.SelectedItem+"'");
```

something wrong with your sql update query i think